# Problems with routing to areas in ASP NET MVC after the project is published

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've created the project in ASP.NET MVC with two areas, and its structure is on the picture:

[image]

When I start it, it takes one of two routes depending on the IP address of the user. the code itself is like this:

```
if (myRole.Count == 0){
    return View ("~/Views/Shared/UserNotFound.cshtml");
 }if ((String.Equals(myRole[0], "Менеджер")) || ((myRole.Count > 1))){
     return RedirectPermanent("/Manager/ManagerHome/Index");
 }else{
     return RedirectPermanent("/Practitioner/PractitionerHome/Index");
 }
```

But as I publish the project its structure is totally different:

[image]

Definitely, there are no folders like "Controllers", "Files" and "Models" in areas (Manager area, for example, presented in this picture). So as I run the project in the web browser I get 404 error. What may cause the problem? Should I change the paths or the project did not publish correctly?

PS: I wonder if this may cause the problem: this project has been re-published - I published it the first time, deleted and republished again in iis. This is my first experience with ASP.NET MVC published applications, so I do not have even a single clue about the reasons for this behaviour.

Thanks to the question of skipper, I provide some additional information: the project has a number of folders, 'Areas' among them. But as I run it on localhost (the project name is Aspid and it is located inside intepub\wwwroot\Aspid) with localhost/Aspid, it goes to localhost/Manager/ManageHome - the path I've written in one of controllers. But the structure of the project lacks Manage/ManagerHome folder. What should be done to run it successfully when it is published?

Comment: It's absolutly correct, that you do not have any cs files like the controller classes. because they are compiled in the bin folder. It seems you have another problem. Are you getting an error 404 even if you open the url '/Manager/ManagerHome/Index' directly from the browser?

Comment: skipper, thank you for your answer. As you may see, there's no folder /Manager/ManagerHome etc. Just /Manager/Views. Moreover, when I run my application on localhost (in iis), it does not run all the path, but just starting from the folder of one of the areas: localhost/Manager/ManagerHome, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Did you right-click Areas and add a new folder instead of area? You're missing the [AreaName]AreaRegistration.cs file which tells the RouteConfig that this is an area.

Make sure you right-click the project or Areas folder > Add > Area.

Comment: foremaro, thank you. I did not quite understand you. The file you mention is located inside one of the folders, and the project runs perfectly when I build it n VS2019. with all the areas accurately embedded.